# Jersey with AngularJs causing 405 error

Tags: java, angularjs, rest, jersey, jersey-1.0

I'm trying to display a simple `String` message in UI through Jersey.

**Web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
          http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">
    <display-name>Sapmle</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**Controller.java**

```
package org.it.bt;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("/")
public class Controller {

    @GET
    @Path("/receive")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public String testApp() throws FileNotFoundException {
        String x = "My name";
        return x;
    }   
}
```

**Controller.js**

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []); 
app.controller('myController',[ '$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){

    $http.get('receive').success(function(res)                   
        {   
            $scope.name = res;                    
        }).error(function(error)
        {
            console.log(error);
        });
}]);
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
       <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
       <title>Task</title>
       <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js">        </script>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="Controller.js"></script>
   </head>
    <body>
        <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
            <h1>{{ name }}</h1>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have included the following jars-

```
asm-all-3.3.1
jersy-core-1.17.1
jersy-server-1.17.1
jersy-servlet-1.17.1
json-20090211
```

When I run in tomcat, I'm not getting any exception and getting `405` method not allowed error. I tried commenting the angular `$http` method and running, still I get the same error.
Any help on this?

Comment: Can you hit /receive directly in the browser (instead of going through the angular page)?

Comment: @AndrewS, YesI tried that but still 405 error. So definitely problem is there with Jersy. Any help on this?

Answer (score 0):

The [error 405](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#4xx_Client_Error) means that a wrong method has bean invoked.

> A **request method** is **not supported for the requested resource**; for example, a GET request on a form which requires data to be presented via POST, or a PUT request on a read-only resource.

In you case your back end (java) expose a GET, but from angular you are invoking a POST.

Correct it and retest.

Comment: Sorry, it was by mistake. I have tried both get and post but still I get the same 405 error.